# Converting excel integer date format to datetime using QGIS

Tags: qgis, convert, excel, date, datetime

How to convert Microsoft Excel date format to datetime format using QGIS?

In example: `43089` in MS Excel is `2017-12-20`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code in field calculator (replace `date_field_name_in_MS_Excel_format` to your date field name):

```
to_datetime('1900-01-01 00:00:00') +  (to_string("date_field_name_in_MS_Excel_format" - 2) +' day')
```