# Converting excel integer date format to date using ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-pro, excel, date

Similar question as this post: [Converting excel integer date format to datetime using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/390206/converting-excel-integer-date-format-to-datetime-using-qgis), but for ArcGIS.

I have a field with integer values like `45118` which came from a column in Excel containing dates which was then converted into an ArcGIS table. I want to convert these values back to dates in ArcGIS. For example, I want to convert `45118` to `7/11/2023`.

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.8 and/or ArcGIS Pro 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

If the source field is numeric, to calculate a date value in a date field from that, simply use Field Calculator with the expression being the source field value and that's it.

Initially this did not work for me, because my source field was string. So in my Field Calculator expression I converted the string to integer using Python, like `int(!source_field!)` and this did what I needed.